# Can I be fired?

Tags: united-states, termination, at-will

I overheard my boss and manager saying very rude things about another coworker and saying if they didn’t show they would be fired. Now, this person’s family member is VERY bad off and I let them know what all was said. Could they fire me for that?

Comment: If they didn't show what? What has the person's family member to do with it? You let the member or the original person know what was said?

Comment: My advice is stay out of it. You have absolutely no idea of the backstory, as to the reason, not showing up for work is the final straw.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty toxic place to work if they can't communicate to a coworker that they need to show up.

Comment: In my experience, by the time things reach this point the employee, unless completely clueless, usually knows that their job is at risk. I'm not convinced that this semi-rumor-mill information would be either necessary or sufficient. There's risk of either side, or both sides, objecting to your getting involved, especially if you don't have a concrete productive suggestion on how to improve things. I understand the impulse, but sometimes inserting yourself into the situation without management backing can make things worse. How sure are _you_ that the potential benefit is worth the risk?

Comment: This could use some improvement... Is the coworker not showing up and not letting your boss/manager know that they cannot show up because of a family member's medical emergency?

Comment: "can I be fired" in an at-will state is kind of like "can I be sued." The answer is always "yes," regardless of whether that is likely or justified.

Answer (score 5):

> Could they fire me for that?

In an at-will state, the answer is "Yes, you could be fired for that."

That probably won't happen. But, yes, it *could*.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your location, for example - in an At-Will state, then the answer is 'yes' they can fire you for no reason.

In a more general sense though, it's unlikely. Hearing a conversation (unless it was a 'private' conversation) and relaying it to another co-worker generally doesn't reach the threshold needed for disciplinary action. I did mention 'Private' conversations, if it was in a closed office and you overheard it, then it's a little more unclear.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it is an at will state.

Comment: In which case you can be fired because you wore socks today.

Answer (score 0):

You did a good thing. You let a coworker know that their job was in jeopardy. Hopefully they were able to use that information to save their job.

They may have needed to discuss their family situation with their manager to better inform them of their crisis. They may have needed to reach out to a outside organization for help. They may need to take advantage of something like family medical leave if that is appropriate.

Hopefully you concentrated your message more about how close they are to losing their job, and not the language the managers were using.

You took a risk. Management might not have liked what you did. You took a risk, your coworker could have reacted badly to the message you were delivering. Both groups could have said you should mind your own business.  When you take a risk you do put your job at risk.

Answer (score 0):

Telling your co-worker that their job is in trouble, probably won't get you fired... It could, but I don't think it is very likely.

However, what you really should do is tell your co-worker about the:
[The family medical leave act](https://www.dol.gov/agencies/whd/fmla). It sounds like your co-worker needs to take time off to support a family member due to a medical emergency, which makes them a protected class.

I would tell your co-worker about it thru email that way you have a paper trail proving that you told your co-worker about FMLA... If your employer fires you because told your co-worker about FMLA. Then you were fired 'in retalation' for telling a co-worker about a labor right that they have. And you will need to contact the state labor board. Explain what you did, what your employer did. And your employer will end up paying you a very, very large lump of money for wrongful termination, because it is illegal to fire an employee for informing other employees about their rights under the law. (As it is A protected action).

It might take a while for everything to resolve. But as long as you have good documentation, you will win.

This might not help your co-worker as they need to qualify for FMLA (50+ employees within 75 miles, and a minimum of 1,250 hours of service during the past 12 months, and care of an immediate family member, birth, serious health condition, etc...) to benefit from it, but at least you tried.

Also note, asking if your employer if qualify for FMLA is a protected action, and you can sue for wrongful termination if you get fired after asking about FMLA (you will need proof that you asked.. email is your friend, CC private email), even if you don't actually qualify for it.

This is one of the things that the DOL actually cares about, and they are a really big hammer.